# xpath on authenticated page in Python

Tags: python, authentication, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am extracting content from page using the below code. But I now want to use this on a page which is in an authenticated page. Is there any way I can do this within python?

Below is sample code am using.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://www.thesiteurl.com/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
logo = tree.xpath('//*[@id="wraper"]/div[3]/header/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img//@src')
print logo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to *get* an authenticated page using `requests` (since you can do whatever you want after you fetch the html)?

If so, it depends on how the page authenticates. The `requests` documentation discusses various ways of doing so here: [link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/). The simplest scheme (username, password) is supported with fairly painless syntax:

```
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```